# how to retrieve any/all related entries?

Tags: entries, relations, entry, query

I have list of banks(institutions) that each one has branches.

> I'm using GraphQL API.

By the bellow code I can get the branches with associated bank(institutions):

```
query branches {
  entries(limit: 50, section: "branches", orderBy: "dateUpdated") {
    id
    branchTitle: title
    ... on branches_standard_Entry {
      branchAddress: map
      bank: institution {
        ... on institutions_standard_Entry {
          bankName: title
          bankLogo: logo {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I want to access data in reverse, getting banks(institutions) and its related branches. There is no possibility or I can't find it.

So how I can get the banks(institutions) with related branches?
I reach to this query:

```
query banks_with_branches {
  entries(section: "institutions", limit: 50) {
    ... on institutions_standard_Entry {
      bankTitle: title
      hqState
    }
  }
}
```

[image: This is the second query explore window that doesn't have the branches to access]
[image: This is the first query that I can access the institutions]

Comment: Bump. We've faced similar issue.

Comment: let me know if you've found any solutions for this
I'm also looking for the answer